# MySQL to Drupal 7 db_select

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-database

I am trying to execute the following mysql query below with drupal 7 db_select. But I cant understand how this can be done. Is anyone can help me to translate the following mysql query into drupal 7 dynamic db query?

My main goal is actually sorting the mysql result by given string position in the name. Please keep in mind that i dont want to fetch all the results and sort them with php, instead I want to use mysql to do that. As i know the "ORDER BY LOCATE" command is doing that exactly.

```
SELECT name FROM `taxonomy_term_data` WHERE LOCATE('credit', name) > 0 ORDER BY LOCATE('credit', name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Proper example of db_select

It is possible, using drupal 7 db_select, here is my example working code (done with help of [this post](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2011-08-31/how-to-sort-database-query-result-by))

My example in with table `cities` containing column `city`. Find cities with double "o" and sort by it's position:

```
$r = db_select('cities', 't')
  ->fields('t')
  ->condition('t.city', '%' . db_like('oo') . '%', 'LIKE');
$r->addExpression("LOCATE('oo', city) ", 'loc');
$r = $r->orderBy('loc', 'DESC')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAllAssoc("id");
```

So similar in your example would be:

```
$r = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't')
  ->fields('t')
  ->condition('t.name', '%' . db_like('credit') . '%', 'LIKE');
$r->addExpression("LOCATE('credit', name) ", 'loc');
$r = $r->orderBy('loc', 'DESC'); //Or ASC
//Execute your query and gather result anyway you want.
```

#### 2. Do you need to use db_select?

As someone stated in comment in link I posted "There are times and places to just use db_query."

I think this is that time :) Dont overcomplicate your code just to use drupal-way logic, which is often outdated or just too simple for complex tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try something like this. `db_like` function seems to do what you are looking for.

```
$result = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd')
  ->fields('ttd', 'name')
  ->condition('ttd.name, '%' . db_like('credit') . '%', 'LIKE')
  ->orderBy('ttd.name', 'DESC')
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Yes, Already i am executing the query in this way but I need to order restults by the position of given string in the name. I am actually not looking for "->orderBy('ttd.name', 'DESC')" instead i am trying to order the result with mysql query "ORDER BY LOCATE('credit', name)". I cant understand how can I translate this query to D7 dynamic query.

Comment: quote missing `->condition('ttd.name' `